# Warp image animations on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image-processing, image-manipulation

just working up to building another app and we'd like to include the ability to animate regions of the screen in response to device shakes/touches etc. For example you could tap the screen and the device would animate a 'poke' into the image at that point (think this would be a lens type effect, like a weight on a trampoline) or you could shake the device and a region or pre-existing object on-screen would wobble (similar to wobble iPhone app)

Can anyone suggest where to get started on including these sort of effects? I'd rather not have to code them from scratch so are there any libraries or examples available (I've looked at cocos2d which seems to only have full screen default transforms)?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the CoreImage library.  You can do basically anything you want with custom shaders.

Comment: As far as i can tell Core Image isn't available in the iPhone SDK.